# Koala Permissions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise, koala

I'm a bit of a noob. So apologies if this is very basic.

My app combines Koala and Devise, to pull just basic information from facebook. Based on my understanding the following permissions are default: `email`, `public_profile`, and `user_friends`.

I've added these permissions to my scope in Koala which is located at the bottom of my devise.rb in my initializers folder as so:

`require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret']
 {:scope => 'user_friends, email, public_profile' , :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}`

However, when I log into the app for the first time with my facebook login - I only see it ask for `email` and `public_profile`.

In addition, I printed out the permissions  `<% permissions = @graph.get_connections('me','permissions') %>` and I get the following:
`[{"permission"=>"installed", "status"=>"granted"}, {"permission"=>"public_profile", "status"=>"granted"}, {"permission"=>"email", "status"=>"granted"}]`

Am I asking for permission incorrectly? Or in the wrong location? Once I get access to `user_friends` I want to pull the `total_count` method. You can find it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends

Click on summary underneath field to see the description.

Any help would be appreciated. My hunch is that the permission isn't being requested, am I doing it in the wrong file?

Answer (score 0):

That permission is approved by default but only will show friends that are also using the app:

> Facebook provides a list of a person's friends that also use your app.
> These friends can be found on the friend list node on the user object.
>
> user_friends: This permission grants the app permission to read a list
> of this person's friends who also use your app. If any of this
> person's friends have chosen not to share their list of friends with
> your app, they will not show up in the list of friends for this
> person. Both people must have enable the user_friends permission
> enabled for a friend to show up in either friend list.

Edit:

I don't see anything wrong with your code. Try with this:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Choose your application in the upper select box. If permissions are requested for that app they should be already marked and you'll have to accept them.

write `me/friends` in the query bar and you can check if you have that permission.

Comment: I totally understand that, but if you look at: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends)
it returns more than a users friends. Can you tell what is wrong with my code to stop me from getting permissions?

Comment: It just shows an empty array for data... If I run it with the graph API it had the extra fields "paging" and "summary" that I need. Any idea why they wouldn't be coming up?

Comment: Perhaps your application is in sandbox mode?

Comment: No the app is live. Unless I don't understand what you mean by sandbox mode. Why would it just return the empty data array ?

Comment: I finally got it working, but it only returns the "data" part of the array with the user information. Not the summary with the total friend count. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can always count the items.